# TeXnic center gives me an extra ' when i type "

Tags: texniccenter

When I try to type a double quote " in a block of text, I always get "'. How can this be stopped?

Comment: I think I asked a duplicate question here. :(

Comment: No you didn't actually! This question is not a duplicate of the linked question; the issue here has nothing to do with keyboard layouts, it's a TeXcenter feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have TeX quotes for the wrong language enabled (probably German?). Go to `Tools > Options > General`, and look at the `Automatic replacement` section. You'll probably want to replace quotation marks with the English "predefined set", which replaces double quotes with `` and `''`.

Comment: I have been using German, it seems. I just changed it to english and it's working.  But all my previous work still has the strange quotation marks. Is there a one-shot way to get everything into english?!

Comment: Global search-and-replace, aka Control-H.

Comment: But both closing and opening quotes are " . How can one distinguish?

Comment: I thought you were asking how to change German-style quote ligatures into English style; look carefully, opening and closing quotes are not the same. If you're asking how to change regular double quotes pasted from elsewhere, that's a different question.

Comment: The opening and closing quotes in the German-style look the same to me... though it's probably because I don't know enough. :(

Comment: Squint a little, or just copy-paste into Replace-search and see for yourself. Open quote is "` (double-quote, backquote), close quote is `"'` (double quote, single quote).

Comment: Lolz! Squinted. And yes,you are absolutely right. I got them the same because I did something incredibly stupid - I deleted the backquote and single quote with a backspace key each time around :D and ended up getting just the double quote.

Comment: Oops.. well in that case search and replace space-doublequote with ``, and doublequote-space with `''`. It'll get you most of them. Then manually search and fix any remaining double quotes...